# how to bind multiple functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript

in the code below, I attach event listener to second Element and on on click it calls First function, which calls second function . in the First , the this.firstElement is defined , but when it gests to the Second function, it throws an error that this.firstElement is undefined.

```
  class Test{
      constructor() {
          this.firstElement = document.getElementById('firstElement');
          this.secondElement = document.getElementById('firstElement');

          this.secondElement.addEventListener("click", this.First.bind(this)); 
      }  

     First() {
         this.firstElement.append('<div> new content </div>')
         this.Second(); 
     }

     Second() {
        this.firstElement.append('<div> another content </div>' )      
     }
  } 
}
```

Comment: you should call `Second()` using `this.Second()`, otherwise you're not calling your object's Second method

Comment: @NickParsons - that was a typo. I have corrected it. I am using this.Second to call it , still I get that error.

Comment: is the error still the same. You also have an issue with `<div> another content </div>'` as you are not opening the string which could be the error you're facing

Comment: @NickParsons  - I'm really sorry , that's another typo. I fixed it. Yes, same error.

Comment: the code you've added here seems to work fine when I test it. Can you create a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) which reproduces your error

Answer (score 0):

Define First and Second using arrow functions instead of class methods. This will auto bind the methods to this.

```
  class Test{
      constructor() {
          this.firstElement = document.getElementById('firstElement');
          this.secondElement = document.getElementById('firstElement');

          this.secondElement.addEventListener("click", this.First); 
      }  

     First =() =>{
         this.firstElement.append('<div> new content </div>')
         this.Second(); 
     }

     Second =() => {
        this.firstElement.append(<div> another content </div>' )      
     }
  }
```

You can also bind the functions to this directly instead:

```
  class Test{
      constructor() {
          this.First = this.First.bind(this);
          this.Second = this.Second.bind(this);
          this.firstElement = document.getElementById('firstElement');
          this.secondElement = document.getElementById('firstElement');

          this.secondElement.addEventListener("click", this.First); 
      }  

     First() {
         this.firstElement.append('<div> new content </div>')
         this.Second(); 
     }

     Second() {
        this.firstElement.append(<div> another content </div>' )      
     }
  }
```

Comment: thanks. do I still need call to bind from the addEventListener or just  following syntax will take care of it . another question is , is this syntax es6 ?                First =() =>

Comment: Yeah, the syntax is es6 and fairly recently added to chrome for that to automatically bind. You wouldn't need the bind anymore elsewhere.